# How to load a new stylesheet when switching from JQuery Mobile site to PC site

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using JQuery Mobile for my mobile site, and am switching between that and my normal full PC site via a `mobile_device?` method from [Railscast#199](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices?view=asciicast)

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :prepare_for_mobile

def mobile_device?
  if session[:mobile_param]
    session[:mobile_param] == "1"
  else
    request.user_agent =~ /Mobile/
  end
end
helper_method :mobile_device?

def prepare_for_mobile
  session[:mobile_param] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
  if mobile_device?
    if request.format == :js
      request.format = :mobilejs
    else
      request.format = :mobile
    end
  end
end
```

This method allows me to switch from my JQuery mobile site to my PC site.

```
<%= link_to "PC Site", :mobile => 0 %>
```

However, it does not load the PC-site stylesheet. Therefore, the page has to be reloaded a second time for the CSS to take affect.

How can I load the CSS on the first try?

**EDIT:**

My stylesheets are added separately to `application.html.erb` and `application.mobile.erb`

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

**application.mobile.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "mobile" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "mobile" %> # this is where my jquery mobile js file is
```

Comment: How do you include stylesshets?

Comment: Hi @rails. I added an explanation as a new edit. I have two separate application layouts, each with its own stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that jquery Mobile defaults to AJAX, so all I needed to do was to disable it as follows.

```
<%= link_to "PC Site", :mobile => 0, "data-ajax" => "false" %>
```